# FindOneAndUpdate of a nested object

Tags: json, mongoose, nested, graphql

I am trying to update a nested object of a JSON. 
I can edit the field, but I can't manage to integrate my positional operator as a variable.

This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Deployment",
  "frequency": "15",
  "lastExecuted": "05.05.2018",
  "maintenanceSteps": {
    "maintenanceStep": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "shortDescription": "ShortDescription",
      "description": "TestDescription",
      "video": "6.1.mp4",
      "image": "LinkToImage",
      "status": "open",
      "duration": "25"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "shortDescription": "ShortDescription",
      "description": "TestDescription",
      "video": "6.1.mp4",
      "image": "LinkToImage",
      "status": "open",
      "duration": "15"
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to set the status:

```
resolve: async function (root, param) {
        let setMaintenanceStepStatus = {};
        if (param.status) {
          if(setMaintenanceStepStatus["maintenanceSteps"])
          {
            console.log("true");
            setMaintenanceStepStatus.maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep[param.id-1].status = param.status;
          }
        console.log("STEP: " + setMaintenanceStepStatus);
        }
        const uMaintenanceStep = await MaintenancePlanModel.findOneAndUpdate({name: param.name},
          { $set:
             {
               "maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep.1.status": param.status,
              }
          }, {
          new: true
        });
        console.log("MSTEP: " + uMaintenanceStep.maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep[param.id-1])
        //uMaintenanceStep.maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep[param.id-1].status = param.status;
        if (!uMaintenanceStep) {
          throw new Error('Error')
        }
        return uMaintenanceStep
      }
```

The problem is with the positional operator in this line:

```
"maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep.1.status": param.status
```

How do I get my param.id in there?

Using

```
"maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep." + param.id + ".status": param.status
```

does not work unfortunately

An alternative idea would be to change the findOneAndUpdate, so I can directly access the maintenanceStep I want to update.

I tried this:

```
const uMaintenanceStep = await MaintenancePlanModel.findOneAndUpdate({name: param.name, "maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep.id": param.id},
```

but I get this error message: "Cannot read property 'maintenanceSteps' of null".

Another idea I had, was using findById and search a maintenanceStep by its objectID, so I don't have to access any nested object. But here I get a Cast error "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ id: '5d63f6e37276ee1b4cdb99c5' }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"maintenanceStep\"

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is, that if you want to pass a concatenated string, you need to pass it as an array:

So the solution is:

```
["maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep." + [param.id-1] + ".status"]
```

Here's the complete code:

```
 resolve: async function (root, param) {
        let setMaintenanceStepStatus = {};
        let one = "maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep." + [param.id-1] + ".status"
        if (param.status) {
          if(setMaintenanceStepStatus["maintenanceSteps"])
          {
            console.log("true");
            setMaintenanceStepStatus.maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep[param.id-1].status = param.status;
          }
        console.log("STEP: " + setMaintenanceStepStatus);
        }
        const uMaintenanceStep = await MaintenancePlanModel.findOneAndUpdate({name: param.name, "maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep.id": param.id},
          { $set:
             {
                [one]: param.status,
              }
          }, {
          new: true
        });
        console.log("MSTEP: " + uMaintenanceStep.maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep[param.id-1])
        //uMaintenanceStep.maintenanceSteps.maintenanceStep[param.id-1].status = param.status;
        if (!uMaintenanceStep) {
          throw new Error('Error')
        }
        return uMaintenanceStep
      }
    },
```